# Anime about a reunited friends who turn out to be each other's fiancee

Tags: ai-yori-aoshi

I would like to re-watch an anime but I can't remember the characters' names or the title. I remember some of the story.

The story starts with a guy at the subway station and he met a girl there who was lost. The girl said she was looking for her fiancé. The guy fixed the girl's sandals which were broken, then they went together to find the house of the girl's fiancé. They went to the address, but it was an empty lot. He took her to his home, where she showed the only photograph she and her fiancé had together. He looked at the photo and it was a photo of him and the childhood friend he was supposed to marry.

Sorry that there isn't a lot to go on.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Thats most probably Ai Yori Aoshi.

[image]

> Kaoru Hanabishi, a college student who lives alone, met a beautiful but bewildered girl dressed in a kimono at a train station. He volunteered to guide her way to the address she was looking for, which happened to be in his neighborhood, but turned out to be an empty lot. Not knowing what to do next, Kaoru invited the devastated girl to his apartment and asked for any additional clues to her destination. She supplied him with a photo of two children whom Kauru immediately identified as himself and Aoi Sakuraba, his childhood friend. It turned out that the girl in front of him is Aoi Sakuraba herself, his betrothed fiancee who came all the way to Tokyo to marry him. Her revelation was not only surprising but also reminded the deepest part of Kaoru's memory for why he left the Hanabishi family in the first place.

[MyAnimeList](http://myanimelist.net/anime/53/Ai_Yori_Aoshi#ukLuKTs2pDyWy1MB.99)